# Picard sequences

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let the problem $$y'=\sqrt{y-1},y(0)=2$$
Compute the 3 first terms of Picard sequences of this problem.

my solution is, we have in general $$y_n(x)=y_0 + \int_{x_0}^x f(s,y_{n-1}(s)) ds$$
here, $y_1(x) = y_0 + \int_0^x \sqrt{y_0-1} ds = \int_0^x ds = x$

$y_2(x) = y_0 + \int_0^x \sqrt{y_1(s) - 1} ds = \int_0^x \sqrt{s-1} ds$
who's $\int \sqrt{s-1} ds$ please?

My last question in this problem is: If the initial continion is $y(0)=1$ (not $y(0)=2)$ how we can prove that the problem $$y' = \sqrt{y-1} , y(0)=1$$ admits a unique solution?

Comment: Do not forget your $y_0$, which is 2 in your case.

Comment: Note that, $ y_1(x) = 2+x $.

Answer (score 1):

$$y_1=y_0+\int_0^x\sqrt{y_0-1}dx=x+2$$
$$y_2=2+\int_0^x\sqrt{s+1}d(s+1)=4/3+\frac{2(x+1)^{3/2}}{3}$$
$$y_3=2+\int_0^x\sqrt{\frac{2(x+1)^{3/2}}{3}+1/3}ds$$
Computation of last one seems complicated.

The integral in 2 is evaluated as:
$$\int x^n dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: Note that, $ y_2 = \frac{4}{3}+\frac{2}{3}(1+x)^{3/2}. $

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand $y_2$ why $d(s+1)$? and in general, how we cal find $\int \sqrt{f(x)} dx$? thank's

Comment: It should be $ds$.

Comment: okay! and in general, how we can find $\int \sqrt{f(x)}$?because I can never remember

Comment: Use substitution $u=s+1$ which gives $ \int_0^x \sqrt{s+1} ds = \int_1^{1+x} \sqrt{u}\, du .$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Edited and correct if still there are mistakes.

Comment: @tiol, the $d(s+1)$ is a kind of substitution which you can do because $d(s+1)=ds$.

Comment: But in general, how we can compute $_int \sqrt{f(x)} dx$ i can't remember it automatically

Comment: @tiol, does edit help?

Comment: No, it's okay. Thank you so much

Comment: If the initial continion is $y(0)=1$ (not $y(0)=2) how we can prove that the problem $$y' = \sqrt{y-1} , y(0)=1$$ admits a unique solution?

Comment: If you know picard lindeloff theorem, you can use it to show uniqueness of solution. Just show that $sqrt(y-1)$ is lipschitz.

Comment: But i show that $y$ est lipscitz in $]1,+\infty[$ and in $y=1$ what we can do?